# Is iTunes on Windows store up to date?

Tags: itunes, windows, software-update

Apple released iTunes update yesterday. Is iTunes on Windows store up to date? In store release date says 2017. 
Is Windows store version updated same day as desktop setup release? 
Are store apps updates checked, pushed automatically? 
I forgot that I installed store version, ended up downloading exe then only I remembered that I'd installed store version.
It seems Apple removed check for updates in iTunes menu.
How to know if my iTunes is up to date?

Comment: Doesn‘t the windows store show when an application was most recently updated?

Comment: @nohillside I decided to check on the Windows Store and for the life of me I can't find anywhere where it lists the date of the last update. All I can see is a release data of 19 November 2017 (which of course makes no sense anyway)! I then checked a few random apps and they're all the same, only the "Release Date" is shown, no indication of when the last update was. Go figure!

Comment: @monomeeth Quality software indeed:-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Apple has only just in recent weeks made iTunes available on the Windows Store.

While it was originally planned to be released at the end of 2017 it ended up taking somewhat longer.

The version of iTunes on the Windows Store is the latest Windows version and, as you've discovered, updates are handled through the Windows Store updater rather than through iTunes directly.

Comment: 12.7.5? Was it updated yesterday then? Is there any way to know for sure?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure on that as I don't use the Windows version. :) It may be that their privacy policy may have been updated in the last few days (because of the EU's GDPR that just came into effect), but not sure on the software itself. Also keep in mind that there will be different versions for different hardware/OS configurations, so an update may or may not be available to you depending on your setup.

Comment: Having said that, as a point of reference, I've got iTunes 12.7.5.9 installed on my Mac and that's the latest version for a Mac running macOS High Sierra. So, the 12.7.5 version you're referencing sounds very current to me! Regardless, the most up-to-date Windows version will be on the Windows Store, regardless of whether that version was released yesterday or not.

Comment: @Aoi: see the press announcement here: http://appleinsider.com/articles/18/05/29/apple-rolls-out-itunes-1275-for-macos-and-windows

Comment: That's right, version 12.7.5 is the main bit (so in my case you can pretty much ignore the .9 at the end because that's still part of the major version of 12.7.5. In my case iTunes was updated yesterday. Maybe I'm missing something about your question? Why are you asking?

Comment: If it's just to make sure you've got the latest version installed, just check its version number. I've just checked and the latest version for Windows is also 12.7.5.9 (assuming your hardware/OS supports it). If you're just wanting to make sure you're downloading the latest version, then the Windows Store will have that and you can download/update it from there. And, if you're not using the Windows Store, you can download [directly from Apple](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/win64).

Comment: I mean I do know latest version no by https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201222,  I forgot that I installed store version, ended up downloading exe just that, then only I remembered that I'd installed store version, then I'd checked store couldn't find anything, so asked if ITunes, apps on store are updated timely in sync with desktop releases

Comment: How do I know my iTunes version no. Windows 10 of course. In store, some version no very confusing in installed apps

Comment: Well, as I mentioned I don't use iTunes in Windows. However, typically in Windows you would be able to go to the Help menu and select the About "App Name" option, so in this case you should be able to go to open iTunes and click on Help > About iTunes to bring up a box that includes the version number.